# adding image in the header of my dev widget

Tags: plugins, images, widgets

i want to add an image to the header of my widget in a div tag like so:

```
<div class="header" align="center">
<a href="http://www.link.com"><img name="Header" src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images/header-background.png" width="280" height="70" alt="plugin header" ></a>
</div>
```

how to get the right path to images folder then display the images ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried: [Wordpress Info on plugin_dir_path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post what i understood is u need to show images saved in your plugin folder.if yes then you can go with plugin_url to link images in a plugin directoy without specifying the plugin folder name.
Example:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="' .  plugins_url('/images/header-background.png', __FILE__) . '" > ';
 ?>
```

The ouput will be like

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/images/header-background.png">.
```

If you are using the plugins_url() function in a file that is nested inside a subdirectory of your plugin directory, you should use like this:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/header-background.png' , dirname(__FILE__) ) . '" > ';
?>
```

If you want to know more about plugin_url() refer [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)